# How to encode Foundation types that already conform to Codable (e.g. TimeInterval) in a custom way?

Tags: json, swift, encoding, swift4, codable

Encoding custom types in a custom way to JSON is easy in Swift 4, and there is good documentation available. But I'm having trouble encoding `Foundation` types in a custom way. My custom types with properties of type `TimeInterval` need to be `Codable` with a JSON format that shows minutes and seconds like this:

```
// my type:
struct MyType: Codable {
    let time: TimeInterval = 65.12
}
// required JSON representation:
"myType": {
    "time": 
    {
        "minutes": 1,
        "seconds": 5.12
    }
}
```

This works fine, if I provide a custom implementation of `encode(to:)` and `init(decoder:)` for each and every one of my types. But I'd like not to repeat myself and simply provide custom versions of these methods for `TimeInterval`. So I tried an extension like this:

```
extension TimeInterval {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case minutes
        case seconds
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        let minutes = (NSInteger(self) / 60) % 60
        let seconds = self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)

        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(minutes, forKey: .minutes)
        try container.encode(seconds, forKey: .seconds)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        guard let minutes = try? values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .minutes), let seconds = try? values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .seconds)  else {
            throw NSError()
        }
        self = TimeInterval(Double(minutes) * 60.0 + seconds)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this code never gets called: encoding a `TimeInterval` value always seems to use the default implementation of encoding a `Double`, which conforms to `Codable` out of the box.

```
let myType = MyType(time: 65.12) 
let encoded = try! JSONEncoder().encode(myType)
let json = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!
print(json)

// prints:
// "myType":
// {
//    "time": 65.12
// }
```

How can I solve this?

**edit:**
Like I wrote in my first sentence, I'm not looking for solutions, how to encode my own custom types. This already works fine in my code. I'm trying to *change* the encoding behavior of Foundation type `TimeInterval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your time interval a read only computed property and add a custom initializer that takes a TimeInterval and initialise your time substructure properties:

```
struct Root: Codable  {
    let myType: MyType
}
struct MyType: Codable {
    let time: Time
    struct Time: Codable {
        let minutes: Int
        let seconds: Double
    }
    init(time: TimeInterval) {
        self.time = Time(minutes: (Int(time) / 60) % 60, seconds: time.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
    }
    var timeInterval: TimeInterval {
        return TimeInterval(time.minutes * 60) + time.seconds
    }
}
```

---

```
let root = Root(myType: MyType(time: 65.12))
do {
    let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(root)
    print(String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!) // "{"myType":{"time":{"minutes":1,"seconds":5.1200000000000045}}}\n
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

**edit/update:**

If you need to add the time property to more that one structure you can move your structure Time out of your custom Type and create a Timed protocol:

```
struct Time: Codable {
    let minutes: Int
    let seconds: Double
}
protocol Timed {
    var time: Time { get }
}
```

Extend Timed protocol adding the timeInterval read-only computed property

```
extension Timed {
    var timeInterval: TimeInterval {
        return TimeInterval(time.minutes * 60) + time.seconds
    }
}
```

Add a custom initializer extending Time:

```
extension Time {
    init(time: TimeInterval) {
        self.minutes = (Int(time) / 60) % 60
        self.seconds = time.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)
    }
}
```

And then you just need to add the Timed protocol to the structures that have a  time property:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let myType: MyType
}
struct MyType: Codable, Timed  {
    let time: Time
}
```

---

Testing:

```
let root = Root(myType: MyType(time: Time(time: 65.12)))
root.myType.timeInterval
do {
    let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(root)
    print(String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!) // "{"myType":{"time":{"minutes":1,"seconds":5.1200000000000045}}}\n
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! As far as I understand, you suggest replacing TimeInterval properties in my types with custom type 'Time', with the required properties and names. That's probably a nice workaround. But do you agree that it's not possible to override encode(to:) and init(from:) on TimeInterval? Is that a feature or a bug? Is there any documentation on that?

Comment: You need to implement the encode method in your Codable structure. Doesn't make any sense implementing it on TimeInterval (Double)

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code (just as an example), and this works.

```
struct MyType {
    let time: TimeInterval = 65.12

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case minutes
        case seconds
    }
}

extension MyType: Encodable {

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        let minutes = 20
        let seconds = 30

        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(minutes, forKey: .minutes)
        try container.encode(seconds, forKey: .seconds)
    }

}

let myType = MyType()
let encoded = try! JSONEncoder().encode(myType)
let json = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!
print(json)
```

---

```
enum MyCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case minutes
    case seconds
}

protocol TimeIntervalEncodable: Encodable {
    var time: TimeInterval {get set}
}

extension TimeIntervalEncodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

        let minutes = (Int(time) / 60) % 60
        let seconds = time.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60)

        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: MyCodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(minutes, forKey: .minutes)
        try container.encode(seconds, forKey: .seconds)
    }
}

struct MyType: TimeIntervalEncodable {
    var time: TimeInterval = 65.12
}

let myType = MyType()
let encoded = try! JSONEncoder().encode(myType)
let json = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!
print(json)
```

Comment: Yes, just an example. Simplified. This is not substantial to the issue. Seems that his time is in hours - for some unclear reason.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for you answer, but like I wrote in my question, I'm looking for a solution, where I do not have to write custom encode methods for all of my custom types separately (I have like 30 types that use TimeInterval). I want to encapsulate that, ideally in a TimeInterval extension.

Comment: Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality. - TimeInterval is already Codable, so you cannot replace already implemented method/initializer by an extension.

Comment: Maybe the protocol extension idea could work for you

Comment: @MichaelBernat by implementing a custom encode method if OP try to add another property to the structure it won't be encoded.

Comment: @LeoDabus Good catch. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelBernat Good point, that I cannot override existing behavior in an extension. I simply forgot about that and felt like I was subclassing... thanks for the reminder. :)